# Are there any free tools to generate 'INSERT INTO' scripts in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The only thing I don't have an automated tool for when working with SQL Server is a program that can create `INSERT INTO` scripts. I don't desperately need it so I'm not going to spend money on it. I'm just wondering if there is anything out there that can be used to generate INSERT INTO scripts given an existing database without spending lots of money.

I've searched through SQL Server Management Studio Express with no luck in finding such a feature. If it exists in SSMSE then I've never found it.

Comment: This is way too little information.  What are you generating the insert into scripts from?

Comment: This question was very useful for me. I am glad someone asked and even happier than somebody gave the right answer

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This web site has many useful scripts including [generating inserts](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/code.htm#inserts).

You can utilise `sp_msforeachtable` with it to generate for an entire DB.

**Update**: There is built-in functionality to script data as INSERTs in SQL Server Management Studio 2008(onwards).

**SQL Server 2008**:

Right-click on your database in SSMS, select `Tasks –> Generate Scripts`, ensure your database is highlighted and click next. Scroll down the options list to the “Table/View Options” section, and change “Script Data” to True.

[image]

**SQL Server 2012**:

Right-click on your database in SSMS, select `Tasks –> Generate Scripts`. Choose the tables you want to generate scripted INSERTs for, then click `Next`.  Choose where you want to send the output to (such as a new Query Window), and then click the `Advanced` button (which for some reason is in the Save to File Section!). Scroll down the options list to the “Types of data to script” option and change it to either "Data only" or "Schema and data". Click `Next` twice.

[image]

[image]

Comment: But had to find an amended one that worked with SQL2005+...http://www.benzzon.se/forum/printer_friendly_posts.asp?TID=86

Comment: I've loved that site for the past year!

Comment: I can not imagine my life without sp_generate_inserts...

Answer (score 16):

you can also use this add-in for SSMS that provides this functionality:
http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/

it also provide other useful features as well.

Comment: +1. I needed to do this today and the SSMS Tools Pack worked great. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Just downloaded it, looks pretty handy.

Comment: This isn't free

Answer (score 4):

Theres a stored proc called "sp_generateinserts" you can google for it. It will take a table and convert it into insert statements.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the express edition but the normal edition of SMSS, you can right click on a tab and script the table as select, insert update to a new window, clipboard or file.

You could also look at MyGeneration or CodeSmith as code generators. I believe they are free and should have soem templates that given a DB will create a bunch of stored procs for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to insert test data, and have fewer than 64K rows to insert, you could use Excel (that's what I do).

For example, if you put values in cells A1, B1, and C1, then entered the following formula in D1, you'd get a usable insert statement:

="INSERT INTO TEST (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ("&a1&","&b1&","&c1&");"

Then just fill down and you can modify the data any time you want.

Answer (score 0):

Not many people know this but you can use sub sonic (http://subsonicproject.com/) to script both the database structure and the data inside it.

The commands are pretty simple ( i use the command line ) eg.

sonic.exe scriptdata /server testserver /db testdb .

This will script all the data into insert statements for you :) , nice and clean.You and also hook this into visual studio if you want to make it easier and not use the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Try DBSourceTools. http://dbsourcetools.codeplex.com 
It has a facility to generate insert scripts for any table in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a free app you can install.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/results.aspx?freetext=Microsoft+SQL+Server+Database+Publishing+Wizard&displaylang=en&stype=s_basic[download here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/results.aspx?freetext=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Database%20Publishing%20Wizard&displaylang=en&stype=s_basic)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the insert into statement from this stored procedure.
http://raresql.com/2011/12/20/how-to-generate-insert-statements-from-table-data-using-sql-server/
But normally we are generating insert into statement like this :

```
    Insert into [table] (...) values (...)
```

But, In this procedure, you can generate insert into statement like this

```
    Insert into [table]
    select * from [table] Union ALL
    select * from [table]
```

So, you can view the data before insertion.

Imran

Answer (score -1):

In SQL Server Management Studio Express, right click on a table in the Object Explorer sidebar and select "Script Table As / INSERT To / New Query Editor Window".

Comment: That doesn't script the contents of the table.

Comment: This answer is not an answer: it is completely wrong. Please delete. (I have marked as not as answer, but a moderator in their wisdom, declined it)