# generation of sql queries on tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a few tables in my local SQL Server database with some data in those tables. I want to to transfer that data to my database server. On that server I can run SQL queries.

How can I generate the SQL to do this, or is this possible using SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/422847/are-there-any-free-tools-to-generate-insert-into-scripts-in-ms-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

First, generate scripts for table structure and run the scripts on your target server, then use the `bcp` tool (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) to migrate the data.

Comment: i have generated scripts please tell abt bcp tool

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understood the original problem - do you have access to the target server so you can run executables on that?

Comment: see 
1> i can run sql queries on my server and with that i have created table structure on my server (firstly  i ran generate script wizard on pc's sql management studio which created a sql script which i ran on my server)
2>now tables on my pc's sql management studio is having some data, i just want to create an sql script to insert data , which  i can run on my server

Comment: also, there is a very similar topic here in Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/422847/are-there-any-free-tools-to-generate-insert-into-scripts-in-ms-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

Take a backup of the database and copy that .bak file to your server, then use `restore database` option of SQL Management studio to restore the database from that .bak file.

Thanks