# How to dump specific tables to a sql script using SQL Server or bcp.exe

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is there a way to dump the content of a few SQL Server tables into a file consisting of standard `INSERT INTO` statements of my SQL Server database?

Comment: As a one-off or programmatically?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/422847/532498

Comment: Yeah, a one-time dump from mssql to another db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Ms Sql Publisher wizard](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5498) . This will help you to create scripts based on your database schema, data or even both. Please check this link if you want to do it in [Visual Studio 2008](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2007/10/15/sql-database-publishing-wizard-is-now-in-visual-studio-orcas.aspx)

Also, there is [this article on codeproject which uses Ms Sql Publisher Wizard](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DatabasePublishingWizard.aspx)

[A step by step process to support my answer.](http://products.secureserver.net/products/hosting/PublishingWithDPW.htm)

Comment: Yes I found this, I was just very surprised that it didn't support it out of the box

Answer (score 1):

If you need it as one-off, look here
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sqlinsertupdategenerator.aspx

Comment: Cheers, but it seems to be having serious problems such as not supporting datetime columns